# Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing in WebAPI projects response header

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have two `.NET Framework 4.6.2` `WebAPI` projects.
Both are using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors v5.2.7.`
Both have `Cors` enabled in their `WebApiConfig.cs` files

```
  var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3725", "*", "*");
  config.EnableCors(cors);
```

If I set a breakpoint in the `WebApiConfig.cs` I see that `Cors` has been enabled in both projects.

[image]
Accessing one of the WebAPIs with my `localhost:3725` client works fine, accessing the other one throws a `been blocked by Cors error`

`jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 OPTIONS http://localhost:54739/logging/Performance 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9600
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
perfLoggerStop @ flogging.js:46
(anonymous) @ JsTodos:106
fire @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3268
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3398
done @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9305
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9548
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9567
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
getAllTodos @ JsTodos:100
onclick @ JsTodos:44
JsTodos:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:54739/logging/Performance' from origin 'http://localhost:3725' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

If I examine the Response Headers of the two WebAPIs in Fiddler the working one contains:
      `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3725`

This is missing in the response header of the failing WebApi, `localhost:54739`.

I built both projects in the same way and have identical versioning of NuGet packages.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the source of the problem or how I could troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ending up being I had an error in my `route` setup.  Why a `CORS` error rather than a `Not Found` error was thrown I do not know.  Be aware that this can happen, mask the underlying error and send you off on the wrong tangent trying to trace down the source of the `CORS` error even though `CORS` is properly configured and working.